# My new internal hard disk doesn't appear in Disk Management, but BIOS and Device Manager recognize it

Tags: hard-drive, device-manager, disk-management

I just connected the new disk to the motherboard and started the computer. BIOS has listed the new and old disks.

Then I went to Disk Management to format it, but it doesn't appear. But I can see it listed in Device Manager.

Moreover, the manufacturer (Seagate) has the tool *Drive Detect*, which detects both of them; and another tool *SeaTools for Windows*, which doesn't detect any (it only detects USB-1394).

**Edit**:

It seems EaseUS Partition Master Home Edition detects it. Should I try to format it with this program, even if WIndows doesn't recognize it?

I have tried adding partition using EaseUS, but it says "There are some error occurred while writing partition chains on disk"

**Edit**: I have just created a spin-off of this question: [How can I make my XP recognize my new internal hard drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/532601/how-can-i-make-my-xp-recognize-my-new-internal-hard-drive)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, it was a driver problem, so I could solve it going to my  motherboard manufacturers' site, and installing SATA drivers, contained within the chipset driver.

(see https://superuser.com/a/532611/186753)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to search for it in the command line program `diskpart`. I've had drives not show  up in disk manager but diskpart sees them. Explore the command line switches (list disk / select disk) to properly locate and format the disk so Windows can use it.

Comment: Thanks, but *list disk* only lists the old one.