# How can I make my XP recognize my new internal hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, device-manager, disk-management

[ This question is a spin-off of [My new internal hard disk doesn't appear in Disk Management, but BIOS and Device Manager recognize it](https://superuser.com/questions/531617/my-new-internal-hard-disk-doesnt-appear-in-disk-management-but-bios-and-device) ]

I bought a new internal Seagate hard disk, connected to the [motherboard](http://www.asus.es/Motherboards/AMD_AM2/M2NMX_SE/#download) and started the computer. BIOS listed the new and old disks (both disks are SATA).

Then I went to Disk Management to format it, but it didn't appear. But I could see it listed in Device Manager.

I discovered that EaseUS Partition Master Home Edition detected it, and tried to format but it said "There are some error occurred while writing partition chains on disk".

Then, I connected the hard disk to another computer (with Windows Vista), and the disk appeared in Disk Management, and I could format it correctly.

I connected it again to my computer, but my Windows XP didn't recognize it. Then, instead of starting my computer from my old disk, I started from a Kubuntu CD. Kubuntu recognized the new disk, so it's not an incompatibility problem between the disk and my motherboard.

Then, I guess it's a XP problem.

How can I fix it?

Comment: You can see it in Device Manager still? Does XP have a driver for it?

Comment: see this [Install a New Hard Drive in Five Easy Steps](http://www.computershopper.com/storage/howto/install-a-new-hard-drive-in-five-easy-steps)

Comment: @Xyon Yes, it's in Device Manager and has a driver. And I checked for new drivers, but it said that there aren't.

Comment: And it doesn't have an error code on the device, it's "Functioning normally"?

Comment: @Xyon Yes, it says "Este dispositivo funciona correctamente.", which in English I think it would be "Functioning normally" (literally, "This device works correctly")

Comment: @arashams Thanks for the link, I haven't configured anything in the BIOS but if Kubuntu recognized the disk, I think that I don't have to change anything, right?

Comment: @DaveRook The problem is that the disk doesn't appear in Disk Management

Comment: @Oriol Quite right, your diagnosis process is basically what I would have done. I'd investigate the device manager pages a little more, I recall in XP there's usually one which tells you what volumes are on the disk, too (though populating it can take a while). Windows **knows** the drive is there, it's just having a tantrum somewhere between activating the hardware and mounting the logical.

Comment: @DaveRook I have 2 hard drives (counting the one that isn't recognized), 1 CD/DVD, 2 cards of RAM, 1 wi-fi card

Comment: @Oriol What size is the new HDD (GB) and what service pack is your XP on?

Comment: @Xyon I have checked Device Manager and it says: "Disk: Disk 1. Type: Unkown. Status: illegible. Style of partition: Not applicable. Capacity: 0MB. Unassigned space: 0MB. Reserved space: 0MB."

Comment: @DaveRook The disk has 2TB and I have XP SP3

Comment: @DaveRook I formatted the disk on another computer (Win Vista), but that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Well, when I formatted it I did a partition with the maximum space. But now EaseUS says that I have: 1MB unallocated, 1.82TB NTFS, and 184.98GB unallocated. Then, the partition is 1.82TB, which is less than 2TB, so maybe the problem isn't the 2TB limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XP SP3 is limited at 2TB -  The 2TB volume limitation is caused by the Master Boot Record (MBR) partitioning scheme that has long been used by Windows 32-bit operating systems such as Windows 2000 and XP.

You could try and use a program like Partition Magic and split it into 1TB chunks!

**EDIT**

Try and remove it from device manager (uninstall) and see if after a reboot it tries to get a driver or similar (or just try to update driver).

Last thing is, go to the manufacturers website, there is a chance you need a driver (or a controller) for it to be seen as a disc! This could exist on the hard drive manufacturers site or the motherboard manufacturers site, and SATA drivers are quite often contained within the chipset driver. So, ensure ALL drives are up to date is my advice.

Comment: Well, when I formatted it I did a partition with the maximum space. But now EaseUS says that I have: 1MB unallocated, 1.82TB NTFS, and 184.98GB unallocated. Then, the partition is 1.82TB, which is less than 2TB, so maybe the problem isn't the 2TB limit?

Comment: If switching from MBR to GPT can resolve this, how can I switch?

Comment: XP does not support GPT.

Comment: I went to the manufacturers website and I found "Seagate does not supply drivers for SATA drives because hard drives themselves do not require specific device drivers" http://knowledge.seagate.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/188411en

Comment: Thanks! After installing the chipset I can see both disks!!!

Comment: Pleasure, glad it is working and sorry we had to try a few things. I am going to delete some of my comments since I've moved them to my answer

Answer (score -1):

Here is one problem that maybe causing it. If for some reason you may have steadily upgraded your system from Windows 98SE through Win2000 or onto Windows XP you may have a residual swap file from Windows 98SE called "WIN386.SWP" still on the HD partition.

Way to fix is start computer with a floppy or CD boot disk, then at DOS prompt type the following pertaining to the Hard Disk Partition that is not being recognised by your XP system , could be E drive, so you type in.... E: then press the ENTER Key. then type.... DELETE WIN386.SWP then simply remove the boot floppy or CD and re-start your computer.

Another problem when using SATA drives along with IDE drives for some unknown reason they do give partition conflicts. Way to go is one SATA and one External. Or simply go on Ebay and purchase a good replacement IDE Drive or Drives and leave out using SATA.

Comment: How would the existence of this old file be causing this issue?  And more importantly, even if it is, how is simply deleting the file going to help?